# Import matlab MAT-format fails

Tags: import, matlab

As I did many times before, after updating Mathematica v12.2  I have problem to import matlab `*.mat` file:

I checked

```
FileExistsQ["d:\\2021\\smallnMi.mat" ] (*True*)
FileFormat["d:\\2021\\smallnMi.mat" ] (*MAT*)
Import["d:\\2021\\smallnMi.mat" ] (*also Import["d:\\2021\\smallnMi.mat" ,"MAT" ] *)
(*Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as MAT format.*)
(*{$Failed}*)
```

Import fails since I updated Mathematica v12.2.  !

What's wrong here? Thanks!

Here I (hopefully) provide my mat-file(Thanks @rafalc) [matfile](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ulrich.neumann/matfile)

Comment: If it worked in 12.1, you should report this to Wolfram. Are you sure it did, with the _same_ file? Mathematica does not support all versions and variants of the MAT format. If you have MATLAB, you can use MATLink to import the data into MATLAB then transfer to Mathematica.  MATLink is way overdue for an update (I just don't have the time), but it still works with R2021a and M12.2 ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for your answer. Until now the combination Mathematica 12.0 & Matlab R2019a worked fine.

Comment: The backend for MAT import has changed in v12.2 that is why you might observe different behavior. Can you share the problematic .mat file?

Comment: @rafalc I would like to but I do not know how!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann unless the file is very large you should be able to upload it to Google Drive, Dropbox, OneDrive or any of the free file hosting sites, e.g. https://zippyshare.com/ and then paste the download link here.

Comment: @rafalc Sorry I don't have access  to these services. Perhaps I' ll find a way with WolframCloud?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann the zippyshare service that I linked does not require any kind of account, so not sure what you mean by not having access. Anyway, you can upload a file to your WolframCloud account and then "Share"-> "Make it public" and just grab the link and paste it here.

Comment: @rafalc Thanks for your patient support. I tried to add the file via wolfram cloud. By the way my business computer enviroment doesn't allow zippyshare & others , don't know why

Comment: @UlrichNeumann unfortunately this is still not right, because the file is private and I cannot download it even after I log in to my WolframCloud account. Please make sure that you select the file, click "Share" then click "Make it public" and then "Get link". The link that you get in the end should not contain your WolframCloud username. 
Or you can use WolframLanguage to do it: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/PutADownloadableFileInTheCloud.html